# asynchronous requests with NSURLConnection: when to release

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsurlconnection

[Apple guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE) is very specific about releasing connection object: it's done in `didFailWithError` and `connectionDidFinishLoading`.

Yet, when I do the same, I later get this in zombi-mode

```
*** -[NSURLConnection releaseDelegate]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1001045b0
```

It seems, there's some code in AppKit which releases connection for me.

I'd be happy to assume that Apple guide is wrong, but do not want to get some terrible memory leak or introduce some subtle incompatibility with older OSX versions or something like that.

Is it safe to ignore documentation in this case?

**edit**
Code creating request

```
  URLConnectionDelegate *delegate = [[URLConnectionDelegate alloc] initWithSuccessHandler:^(NSData *response) {
      ...
  }];
  [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:delegate];  

  // I do not release delegate when testing for this issue, not sure whether I should in general
```

Delegate class itself

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
  successHandler(receivedData);

  [receivedData release];
  Block_release(successHandler);

  // do we really need this????????
  [connection release];
}
```

Comment: From the docs: ‘`NSURLConnection` retains its delegate when it is initialized. It releases the delegate when the connection finishes loading, fails, or is canceled.’ It looks like you have over-released the delegate.

Comment: @Bavarious I don't release delegate here. (whether I should is another question) Error appears when I add `[connection release];` and goes away when I remove it.

Comment: @Bavarious Also, error wording suggests that method `releaseDelegate` was invoked on released `NSURLConnection` instance. Not on delegate.

Comment: Which object is the URL connection delegate? What is its lifecycle?

Comment: Hmm, maybe. I’m not familiar with zombies. Would you be willing to paste the code that creates the connection and handles its delegate methods?

Comment: @Bavarious Delegate isn't referenced from anywhere, except inside the connection. I have no problem with sharing project code in general (it's only a toy), except being slightly ashamed of it :)

Comment: @Bavarious: Quick summary: When zombies are enabled, objects become zombies instead of deallocating. When you send a message to a zombie object, it moans, either into the console (NSZombieEnabled) or into Instruments' timeline (Zombies instrument). This is very useful for hunting down over-release/under-retain bugs.

Comment: @Bavarious Não, tempo é lindo, mas eu gasto muito tempo em programação :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you’ve created your connection with

```
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:delegate];
```

you don’t own that connection object, hence you shouldn’t release it.

That being said, I wouldn’t recommend it. If you don’t own an object, you have no guarantee that it will outlive autorelease pool drain cycles, i.e., it could be the case that your connection object is (auto)released before it’s finished loading. Instead, create a retain declared property to hold the connection:

```
@property (retain) NSURLConnection *connection;
```

assign your connection object to the declared property:

```
self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request
    delegate:delegate];
```

and, when the connection finishes loading or fails, release it by assigning `nil` to the declared property:

```
self.connection = nil;
```

As for your delegate, if it only needs to exist whilst the connection is loading, you can autorelease it since the connection retains the delegate:

```
URLConnectionDelegate *delegate = [[[URLConnectionDelegate alloc]
    initWithSuccessHandler:^(NSData *response) {
    // …
}] autorelease];

self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request
    delegate:delegate];
```

Comment: Thank you, I see it more clear now. But wouldn't it be easier to create collection with `alloc` then? I create several in a loop and would have to employ dictionary or set, but issue `NSDictionary` and others cloning their keys would make it tricky.  So, do you think a solution with `alloc` and `release` is valid?

Comment: @NikitaRybak Yup, you could create them with `alloc`, not assign them to retain declared properties or some other ownership mechanism, and release them upon finish/fail if that better suits your application architecture. I usually recommend keeping a reference to the connection because it allows one to cancel (and release) it regardless of the connection having finished downloading or failed. As for using a dictionary (which needs to copy the keys), you could use an array instead (which retains its objects) or a simple class mapping a connection to an object that can be copied (e.g. string).

Comment: Is this post true? In some cases where you start an indendent activity, it retains itself and there is no need retain it yourself. NSURLConnection may retain itself until the connection is finished or has an error. An similar example is UIAlertView. You don't have to retain it after its shown even through it appears after you've shown it. It retains itself until the user dismisses it.

Comment: @David, UIAlertView doesn't "retain itself". When you call `show`, it's added as a subview of your window, so the window retains it. When you dismiss it, it removes itself from its superview, which brings its retain count to 0, and it is deallocated.